# Margin of Titles

Tags: spacing, sectioning

I'm learning LaTeX and there is a problem i encountered:
On the top of a new page a huge margin appears, though I declared a top margin of 2 cm. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: It depends on how `\chapter` is defined in the class you are using (and I can't read the `\documentclass` line well enough to tell).  The output, however, looks similar to the standard `report` class....

Comment: You can modify your `.cls` file, you are using. Just search for commands to minimize the spacing in the document and add in the `.cls`.

Comment: Care! When you do so, you really have to provide a different name for the modified class file. However, appling custom patches in actual mantained class files should not be a standard practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\titlesec` can help you here. Add the following code to your preamble:

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
              {0cm}     %left: indentation of the title
              {0cm}     %space above the title
              {1cm}     %space after the title
```

The most important point for you, is to set the fourth parameter ('space above') to 0 length. The other ones can be changed deliberately.

Comment: Thanks, but topMargin was 3 cm, not 2. I did a crutch, but how?
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0cm}{-1cm}{1cm}

Comment: @XaveScor, in your example preamble you declared '2cm' and your post contained this information, too. The exact value isn't the point. Just enter whatever you please. If you will declare 'top=3cm' in `\geometry` but you want to have 2cm space when starting a chapter, the code in your comment is alright.